# CustomloaderDep cannot be cast to CustomloaderDep?

Tags: java, classloader

I am getting `java.lang.ClassCastException: CustomloaderDependency cannot be cast to CustomloaderDependency` I know reason is two classes are loaded by different classloaders(one by `customclassloader` and another by default `sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader`)

My custom class loader is not being used even after running the program with `-Djava.system.class.loader=CustomClassLoader` until and unless i am not explicitly  doing `Class.forName("CustomloaderDependency", true, ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader() );` but when i do `new CustomloaderDependency() default sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader  is used`

**Here is my custom class loader**

```
   public class CustomClassLoader extends ClassLoader {


     public CustomClassLoader() {
            super();
        }
    /**
     * This constructor is used to set the parent ClassLoader
     */
    public CustomClassLoader(ClassLoader parent) {
        super(parent);
    }

    /**
     * Loads the class from the file system. The class file should be located in
     * the file system. The name should be relative to get the file location
     *
     * @param name
     *            Fully Classified name of class, for example com.journaldev.Foo
     */
    private Class getClass(String name) throws ClassNotFoundException {
        String file = name + ".class";
        byte[] b = null;
        try {
            // This loads the byte code data from the file
            b = loadClassFileData(file);
            // defineClass is inherited from the ClassLoader class
            // that converts byte array into a Class. defineClass is Final
            // so we cannot override it
            Class c = defineClass(name, b, 0, b.length);
            resolveClass(c);
            return c;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Every request for a class passes through this method. If the class is in
     * com.journaldev package, we will use this classloader or else delegate the
     * request to parent classloader.
     *
     *
     * @param name
     *            Full class name
     */
    @Override
    public Class loadClass(String name) throws ClassNotFoundException {
        System.out.println("Loading Class '" + name + "'" );
        if (name.contains("CustomloaderDependency") || name.contains("TestCustomLoader")) {
            System.out.println("Loading Class using CustomClassLoader");
            return getClass(name);
        }
        return super.loadClass(name);
    }

    /**
     * Reads the file (.class) into a byte array. The file should be
     * accessible as a resource and make sure that its not in Classpath to avoid
     * any confusion.
     *
     * @param name
     *            File name
     * @return Byte array read from the file
     * @throws IOException
     *             if any exception comes in reading the file
     */
    private byte[] loadClassFileData(String name) throws IOException {
        /*InputStream stream = ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(
                name);*/
       // FileInputStream stream = new FileInputStream("F:\\workspaces\\test\\Test\\bin\\"+name);
        FileInputStream stream = new FileInputStream("F:\\"+name);
        int size = stream.available();
        byte buff[] = new byte[size];
        //DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(stream);
        stream.read(buff);
        stream.close();
        return buff;
    }
}
```

**Here is my testing class**

I am running this program with `-Djava.system.class.loader=CustomClassLoader` but still looks like default class loader is used for classes with which i am trying to downcast with

```
    public class TestCustomLoader {

            public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException, InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException {

            Class classObject = Class.forName("CustomloaderDependency", true, ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader() );
            Object customloaderDependency = classObject.newInstance();

            System.out.println("classloader from my custom is "+customloaderDependency.getClass().getClassLoader());
           // above prints CustomClassLoader@15db9742

            System.out.println("classloader for casting is "+CustomloaderDependency.class.getClassLoader());
           // above prints  sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@14dad5dc

            CustomloaderDependency finalObject = (CustomloaderDependency)customloaderDependency;
          //above line i am getting exception


        }
```

Comment: You have instantiated a class that was loaded by your custom class loader. Mentioning the class in your main program lets it load by the system class loader. You obviously know the reason behind the error message. I do not understand what problem you have with it. Could you be more detailed?

Comment: i am getting class cast exception at `CustomloaderDependency finalObject = (CustomloaderDependency)customloaderDependency;` it means customloaderDependency object is loaded by customclassloader but CustomloaderDependency  with which i am downcasting is by  ` sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader`

Comment: Yes, the _statically_ mentioned class (the word in the cast parantheses) is loaded by the system class loader who already loaded the main class and all its dependents, whereas the class of the object referred to by the variable `customloaderDependency` was loaded by your custom class loader.

Comment: but system classloader is mine customclassloader as i am running the pragram with `Djava.system.class.loader=CustomClassLoader`. So should not even my the statically mentioned class (the word in the cast parantheses) and main class also be loaded by customclassloader?

Comment: Hmmm ... You are right. But for me it works: Using your setup (with console output), I first get three output lines from the custom class loader. So it is used and it works. You must have some other issue  ...

Comment: Thanks @Seelenvirtuose i got it work. You provided me good data points like dependents are loaded from same classloader from which it is being called by default

Answer (score 0):

I got it work by

```
  @Override
    public Class loadClass(String name) throws ClassNotFoundException {
        System.out.println("Loading Class '" + name + "'" );
        if (name.contains("CustomloaderDependency") || name.contains("TestCustomLoader")) {
            System.out.println("Loading Class using CustomClassLoader");
            return getClass(name);
        }
        return super.loadClass(name);
    }
```

Before above fix, call was coming to my customclassloader to load `TestCustomLoader` but i was loading it through `Launcher$AppClassLoader` because of `if (name.contains("CustomloaderDependency") ) {`.

Hence all it dependents(like statically mentioned class i.e the word in the cast parentheses) were also being loaded by `Launcher$AppClassLoader`